# Does the sequence $x_{n+1} = \lambda x_{n} (1-x_{n})$ with $\lambda \in [0,4]$ and $x_{0} \in [0,1]$ converge for all $x_{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title says, I wonder if the sequence $x_{n+1} = \lambda x_{n} (1-x_{n})$ with $\lambda \in [0,4]$ and $x_{0} \in [0,1]$ converge for all $\lambda$? I created some code to see this, and I find that for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ the sequence converges to $0$, then it gradually increases until the interval $\lambda \in [3.5,4],$ where it seems to be very chaotic. The value of $x_{0}$ does not really seem to matter too much. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$?

Comment: I would say $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}=\lambda(1-x_{n})$, which would be less than one for $\lambda<1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115568/why-does-the-logistic-map-x-n1-r-x-n1-x-n-with-x-0-in-0-1-diverge-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that
$$(\forall x\in[0,1])\;\; 0\le x(1-x)\le \frac 14 $$
**hint**

By induction, we prove easily that
if $0\le x_0\le 1$ then
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N) \;\; 0\le x_n\le \frac{\lambda}{4}\le 1$$
since $$0\le \lambda \le 4.$$

So $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Observe that we can assume that $$0<x_0\le \frac 12$$

If $\lambda\in [0,2]$ then

$$\forall n \;\; x_n\in [0,\frac 12]$$

in this case the sequence is decreasing and consequently converges to the fixed point zero.

Comment: thanks, this makes total sense.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. And there's no monotonicity for growing $\lambda$, cf the above comments to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Note that :  if $$0\leq x \leq 1\to x(1-x)\leq \frac 14$$It is easy to proof

so $$0\leq x_n \leq 1 \to 0\leq x_n(1-x_n)\leq \frac 14 \\
x_{n+1}\leq 1\to \\
\lambda x_n(1-x_n)\leq 1\to \\
\lambda \times max\{{x_n(1-x_n)}\}\leq 1\to\\
\lambda \times \frac 14\leq 1\to\\$$
can you take over now?

Comment: @Khosratash, c'mon, stop bluffing. :)